# Windows 2008 r2 debugview (OutputDebugString) issue

Tags: permissions, windows-8, debugview, outputdebugstring

Hi we are installing x86 application as a service on windows 2008 R2 which is using OutputDebugString for debug messages.

The problem is that DebugView utility catches the debug output from the application only when application is run from console in elevated mode and not as a service.

I haven't found any KB that talks directly about this limitation of OutputDebugString in windows 2008 R2.

Anyone encountered such a problem? 
Is there such limitation really exists?

UPD: We are using TerminalServices if that important for performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

To capture these messages from a service (running in a different session), go to the "Capture" menu in DbgView and choose "Capture Global Win32".